# How to use Boolean parameters as build parameters to copy artifacts?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have a multi job project PJ1 with Boolean parameters A, B,C. Based on which parameter is chosen, I want the PJ1 to copy artifacts from another job like if A the copy from "TestA47", if B then copy from "TestB47", if C then copy from "TestC47". How can I pass the dynamic Boolean parameter selection to the Copy artifacts plugin?

If it was a choice parameter then each selection would have a name and I can pass that as ${Name} to the copy artifacts. But for Boolean I don't understand how to do it

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would rather suggest to use a choice parameter... Unless you want to give the opportunity to have artifacts of more than one other project. In this case you should consider a Pipeline Job, where you have extended possibilities by using Groovy.

Comment: I wish I could use Choice parameter. But I need to have Boolean parameter for multiple selections at a time. Could you please elaborate on the second part of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I use Boolean parameters like so in scripted pipelines ..

I've defined a parameter as type Boolean, and if it's checked during run-time (true), then I do something. My Boolean parameter is called "A"

```
if (env.DoItOrNot.toBoolean()) {
   println "A was checked, copying artifacts"
   copyArtifacts(
      projectName: '${JOB_NAME}',
      filter: '**/*.txt',
      fingerprintArtifacts: true,
      flatten: true,
      selector: specific(prereq_build.getId())
    )
} else {
   println "A was not checked, skipping"
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have added images for better understanding.. My Build is parameterised with Boolean. I want to use that in Copy Artifacts. If it was a string parameter I can use ${A} as in image 2. I want something like that for Boolean

Comment: I see, I had assumed that you wanted to do it via Groovy (pipeline), I'm not sure how you'd reference a boolean that way in a freestyle project.